# Multiple buttons and one button is not reacting at click event

Tags: java, android

i have a main-activity and in the OnCreate() i instantiate 81 buttons(class MyButton derived from FrameLayout). In the class MyButton in the constructor i create the Eventhandler onClick(). I set a breakpoint in the onClick()-function(at the if-statement). When i debug the app and i click to a button, the app stops in the onClick()-function for all buttons, but not for the button[8].
Has someone an idea why?

Here the code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public MyButton[] buttons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int i;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GridLayout myGrid=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        buttons=new MyButton[81];
    for(i=0;i<81;i++) {
        buttons[i]=new MyButton(this,i);
        myGrid.addView(buttons[i]);
    }
  } 
}

public class MyButton extends FrameLayout {

public int Position;

public MyButton(Context context,int pos) 
{
    super(context);
    Position = pos;
    .
    .
    .
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v instanceof MyButton ) {
                MainActivity ma=(MainActivity)v.getContext();
                if(ma.sudAct!=null) ma.setButton(Position);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This code won't compile. Please update your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing a line similiar to this in your onCreate method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Change the `R.layout.main` constant into the constant referring to layout for your activity, place the line right after this line: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`